# Why my variable is not accessible in forEach()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope

I am trying to understand why I cannot access the variable `i` from inside the `forEach()` function at the bottom. Could someone help me please?

```
draw() {
    this.players.forEach( (player, i) => {
      let cardElements = [];

      player.cards.forEach( (card) => {
        let cardElement = document.createElement("div")
        cardElement.classList.add("card")
        cardElement.setAttribute("suit", card.suit)

        let cardValue = document.createElement("div")
        cardValue.classList.add("value")
        cardValue.textContent = card.value

        cardElement.append(cardValue)

        cardElements.push( cardElement )

      });

      cardElements.forEach( (cardElement) => {
        document.getElementById(`player-${i}`).append(cardElement)
      });

    })
  }
```

Comment: Have you logged the interpolated to see what the result is?

Answer (score 2):

String interpollation works with `${i}` not `$i`

```
document.getElementById(`player-${i}`).append(cardElement)
```

Comment: Well spotted but still have the same problem.

Comment: Sorry it is working as expected now. Thanks!